# ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiple-input

My (Keras) model has two inputs of different shapes. The [example](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models) on Keras website says it should work.

I defined the inputs as follows:

```
model1 = Model(inputs=[uii,  vji], outputs=[decoded,decoded2, prod])
model1.summary()


Model: "model_10"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_49 (InputLayer)           [(None, 1682)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_51 (InputLayer)           [(None, 943)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But when fitting the model:

```
model1.fit([matrix, matrix.T], [matrix, matrix.T,matrix.reshape(-1)])
```

It produces the following error:

> /tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_array_lengths(inputs, targets, weights)
>       733     raise ValueError('All input arrays (x) should have '
>       734                      'the same number of samples. Got array shapes: ' +
>   --> 735                      str([x.shape for x in inputs]))
>       736   if len(set_y) > 1:
>       737     raise ValueError('All target arrays (y) should have '
>
> ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of
>   samples. Got array shapes: [(943, 1682), (1682, 943)]

Any solution to fix this kind of error? Thanks

Comment: Firstly, you have 2 x inputs and 3 y inputs.

Comment: It is possible to have different numbers of input and output. For example, 2 inputs, 1 output, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you've not provided the information regarding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. It is the **length** of the inputs must be identical. So, I modify the input data to the same length, as well as the output.

For example: I set the length of both input to 1682 by pre-processing the data.

```
The shape of input1 can be (1682, 943)
The shape of input2 should be (1682, 1682)
```